# Subversion with Netbeans and good practices for multiple versions

Tags: svn, netbeans

I am looking at working with Subversion using Netbeans and wondering how easy it is to maintain different versions (branches) of code.

We currently have Sourcesafe with a single version of the code which is maintained in Netbeans.  Now we have more customers, therefore we need to maintain different versions of the software.

As I understand in Subversion, you have a trunk folder which is the main/working branch of the code.  Then as different versions are required you branch the code under the branches.  So thinking about how things may look in future the following hierarchy might be used:

```
product\trunk
product\branches\version 1.0.0.0
product\branches\version 1.0.0.1
product\branches\version 1.0.0.2
product\tags
```

Under trunk and each version (i.e. version 1.0.0.0, version 1.0.0.1, and version 1.0.0.2) you have the same folder hierarchy of the Netbeans project, i.e.:

```
src
lib
test
```

Where lib contains JAR files used by the project that may be developed by 3rd parties.  src will contain the tens, hundreds, thousands of source code classes used by the application.  test will hopefully contain the test classes for the equivalent source code classes.

nbproject is a folder specifically used by Netbeans to store the various project settings.
Netbeans typically creates a dist folder when you compile your application which is a compiled JAR file and the JAR files it references in a lib folder.

There are a couple of questions I have:

1. Is there any reason not to add the nbproject, lib and dist folders to version control?
2. When maintaining the different versions of code within Netbeans, do you have to create a separate Netbeans project for each version of source code?  So essentially you would have in your projects view in Netbeans:

   - Product Trunk
   - Product Version 1.0.0.0
   - Product Version 1.0.0.1
   - Product Version 1.0.0.2
   - ... and so on ...
   - Product Version X.X.X.X

From what I have seen Subversion has better merging functionality than Sourcesafe and many other better features.  It also integrates with Netbeans which is another big plus.  I have already created a test repository with a trunk and a single branched version where I have merged files from the branched version back into trunk with a number of conflicts in the same file.

Answer (score 1):

Typically one avoids the use of spaces in directory and file names as it improves the ability to script.  While scripting is not an immediate concern, you don't want to shut the doors to such a useful tool (should you need it in the future).

So try this instead

```
product/
product/trunk
product/branches/1.0.0
product/tags/1.0.0.1
product/tags/1.0.0.2
product/tags/1.0.0.3
```

Where one "makes" the 1.0.0 branch by copying in from the trunk.  While stabalizing the 1.0.0 branch, work for 1.0.1, 1.1, or 2.0 can continue in the trunk without upsetting the 1.0.0 branch

Now when you are ready to "release" a copy of the 1.0.0 branch, you copy it into the "tags" directory with an increasing "release" number.  Just after you copy it into the "tags" you should reconfigure your server to not allow any updates to 1.0.0.1, 1.0.0.2, etc.  Otherwise you will not have a valid snapshot of what you released.

This is just one way of doing things, and a way that is quite popular.  That said, there are many variants and you might find an improvement which better suits your needs.

Answer (score 0):

**Notes**

- Tree layout and names of dirs are just conditional agreement, i.e you can have mainline/vesions/releases f.e instead of trunk/branches/tags (merge/copy will work with *any URLs*)
- Branches usually used some (long) time for WIP, thus - separating branches for **every build** isn't, most time (I see) "branch-per-minor" policy

**A couple of answers**

1. nbproject folders - I don't know which data stored in it, how much it usable for 3-party developer, but common rule for SCM is "versioning only data, which is a **must** for starting work with a projects from a ground in any new place". If nbproject contains only your-specific or thisworkplace-specific settings, it can and have to excluded from repository saving
2. You can, it's just more usable (because settings from nbproject can differ from version to version and you don't store settings inside repo for each version /branch?/), but "taste can differ" - you have to test and detect *your way*
3. Not asked, but answered - dist folder also **must be excluded** from versioning - build's artifacts haven't any historical value in the light of *Source Control* (and can be always easy re-created for any recoded revisions - see answer N1 regarding "common rule")